# Overriding Class Module methods from a parent class

Tags: ruby, object, inheritance, module

I've got this rudimentary example

```
module TheirModule
  class Klass

    def self.do_something
      KlassModule.klass_module_method()
    end

    module KlassModule

      # Lots of other functionality

      def self.klass_module_method
        puts "Hello from TheirModule"
      end

      # Lots of other functionality

    end
  end
end

module MyModule
  class Klass < TheirModule::Klass

    module KlassModule
      extend TheirModule::Klass::KlassModule

      def self.klass_module_method
        puts "Hello from MyModule"
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Then calling this gives me unexpected results.

```
MyModule::Klass.do_something  # Hello from TheirModule
```

My expectation is that `MyModule::Klass`'s `KlassModule` will redefine the `klass_module_method` originally defined in `TheirModule::Klass`'s `KlassModule` like this...

```
MyModule::Klass.do_something  # Hello from MyModule
```

this clearly isn't the case and I'm wondering...

- Why this doesn't work?
- What would be a ruby way to accomplish this?

**EDIT**: The one caveat is that I cannot edit the source of `TheirModule`

Comment: Who should redefine what? That's a lot of confusing names.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `MyModule::Klass.klass_module_method` should override `TheirModule::Klass.klass_module_method` ... Or at least that's what my intention is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work without modification of original code of `TheirModule`.

There are two KlassModules

- `TheirModule::Klass::KlassModule`
- `MyModule::Klass::KlassModule`

Within `TheirModule::Klass` name `KlassModule` unambiguously resolves to `TheirModule::Klass::KlassModule`. That another module you define is completely separate from this one. It can't redefine anything.

You need to open and alter the original module, `TheirModule::Klass::KlassModule`. Like this, for example.

```
module MyModule
  class Klass < TheirModule::Klass

    module ::TheirModule::Klass::KlassModule
      def self.klass_module_method
        puts "Hello from MyModule"
      end

    end
  end
end

MyModule::Klass.do_something
# >> Hello from MyModule
```

Though I'd say this does not look a very ruby way. Maybe classes and modules can be reorganized to achieve this in a cleaner way.

Comment: Without access to `TheirModule` directly, this solved my problem.  Thank you.

Comment: Small problem (not sure if this is a problem for the OP): this global shanges the behavior of `klass_module_method` for every single subclass of TheirModule::Klass.

Comment: @Linuxios: yeah. He could instead replace lookup syntax to `self::KlassModule`. However, that could also break some client code.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I know, I just wanted the OP to know in advance.

Comment: @Linuxios Understood, thanks for noting that.  In my case (in an application) this is not an issue, as this is the only subclass.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple fix. Try this for `self.do_something`:

```
def self.do_something
  self::KlassModule.klass_module_method()
end
```

This forces the method to look up `KlassModule` in the context of the current class.

Comment: I don't have access to the `TheirModule` Sorry this was not clear in the question.

Comment: @jondavidjohn: I see. Then whoever designed TheirModule, if it was meant to be extensible, designed it very badly. Hold on a moment.